# When using Hibernate table-per-class, how do I prevent table creation for the base class?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two classes: a BaseClass and an ExtendedClass that extends BaseClass.  I would like to persist ExtendedClass to a single DB table using Hibernate, and I want it to also persist all the fields from BaseClass.

I think I want to use the table-per-class paradigm, however I don't want Hibernate to create a DB table for BaseClass (and I don't want to add an @Id to BaseClass either).  Is there a way to suppress this?

I am doing something like this:

```
@Entity
class BaseClass {
  int value1;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="extendedClasses")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
class ExtendedClass extends BaseClass {
  @Id long id;
  int value2;
}
```

And I want the DB to have a single table like this:

```
table extendedClasses
(
 long id
 int value1
 int value2
)
```

Comment: I would say just don't annotate the baseclass as an entity

Comment: I tried that but it won't persist the base class fields without the Entity.  I tried Embedded too, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put `@Entity` on the base class, you must define an id and that will generate a table in your database.

Replacing `@Entity` with `@MappedSuperclass` produces the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, but it won't persist the base class fields without the @Entity annotation.

Comment: when i try to add both i get "Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: An entity cannot be annotated with both @Entity and @MappedSuperclass" is there an other solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try marking the base class as abstract

```
@Entity
abstract class BaseClass {
  int value1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I read that would work, but unfortunately I need to instantiate the base class in my code.

Answer (score -1):

To stop hibernate from creating tables in DB add this to persistence.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
```

I don't know about your specific case for base & sub class.

Comment: Thanks, but I do want it to create a table for the ExtendedClass